# Add to main graph all at once

Tags: tensorboard

Is it possible in Tensorboard to `Add to main graph` all elements at once? Every time when I load a graph I see this picture. And adding all elements manually takes minutes. I could not find a way to add all to see the whole graph. Is it possible?

[image: Graph]

Answer (score 1):

You can scope all elements in a common name scope when building the computational graph.

It's not a solution, but shows you the whole graph.

[image: screenshot]